# Retrofit URL Problem using PUT-Request with colon in Path

Tags: android, url, retrofit2

I am confused using retrofit with a PUT-Request containing path elements with a colon (":") in the var. It should change the colon to "%3A" but it doesn't and i get a 400 Error Response from the backend.

```
@PUT("/api/2/elements/{elementId}/features/{featureId}/options")
Call<String> updateThingRFIDTag(
        @Header("api-token") String token,
        @Header("Authorization") String base_auth,
        @Path("elementId") String elemnentId,
        @Path("featureId") String featureId,
        @Body String optionTag
);
```

The Request URL looks like: https://pageurl.com/api/2/elements/com.element.d3:f4345-43234-5654d-33/features/com.featurelistings.powersign:1.0.0/options

When I use Postman the it works perfectly and the Request URL after hinting send looks the same except the colons(':') changed to '%3A'... 
I already tried to use encode boolean = true in the path argument - doesn't help.
I already tried to change the base url an the path attr. before the request to '%3A'. But then retrofit encodes the '%3A' to soemthing else and I still get an error response. Can soemone help? I already work on this the last 3 days... Besides an http Interceptor doesn't help at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried to look at output request line/structure in some proxy app like Charles? There you can see a real line.

Comment: does this make any difference to retrofit? I can use the instance call and response with methods like url() etc. I can see exactly how the request looks like in log levels. Is there something more beneficial about using Charles?

Comment: You said that even if you replace all ":"  with "%3A" characters manually before put parameters in request, then it change them to "something else", may be it is a real issue of the lib and with proxy app you may see what actually comes to server.

Comment: I'll give it a try...

Comment: If I replace ":" with "%3A" retrofit replace it with "%253A".